# Swift tableview populating cells results in mixed up contents

Tags: swift, uitableview, alamofire, firebaseui

within my app, I am populating a tableview with custom cells, filled with data pulled from Firebase using the FirebaseUI library.

Furthermore, I am inserting favicons I get from open graph data into the cell. What I am stuck at, is when you move the table up and down, the favicons get asserted to cells where they don't belong to.

For example:
Cell 1 contains a link to a reddit post, therefore getting assigned the reddit favicon.
Cell 2 contains a link to a site which doesn't have a favicon set, thus initially it is empty.

Now if you drag the table up and down, what happens is that this cell will get the reddit favicon set as well. After a while, almost every cell without a favicon, will have a (wrong) favicon set.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.dataSource = self.tableView.bind(to: getQuery()) { tableView, indexPath, snap in

        self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cellident", for: indexPath)
        let customCell = cell as! CustomCellTableViewCell
        let theURLString = self.getURLString(obj: snap)

        let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "scrapequeue")
        serialQueue.sync {
            self.scrapeFavicon(inputURL: theURLString, customCell: customCell)
        }
    }
}

func scrapeFavicon(inputURL: String, customCell: CustomCellTableViewCell) {

    OGDataProvider.sharedInstance.fetchOGData(urlString: inputURL) {

        [weak self] ogData, error in
        if let _ = error {
            return
        }
        let imageURL = ogData.imageUrl
        let imageNSURL = NSURL(string: imageURL)

        customCell.FaviconView.af_setImage(withURL: imageNSURL as URL)

    }
}
```

Question: Is this a asynchronous problem, or am I completely missing something here?

When I scroll towards the end of the table and go back up and repeat this, the cells have different images every time.

Comment: Do note that table view cells are re-used when you scroll through a table view. So, my suspicion would be that you are not setting the icon unless an icon is set and are not clearing the icons for cells where there is no icon. Does that make sense? If not, can you post the `cellForRowAt:` method from your table view delegate?

Comment: @Fahim I don't have that method actually.

Comment: How are you creating the cells for your table view then?

Comment: The above bindings provided by the FirebaseUI library do that.

Comment: I missed that sorry, I have a possible solution, will post it as an answer since I can't format code correctly in a comment ...

Answer (score 0):

In `scrapeFavicon`, modify the following error handling condition:

```
if let _ = error {
    return
}
```

To set the image to `nil`. I have not used the FirebaseUI library and so I don't know the exact code to use, but if `FaviconView` is a `UIImageView`, you should be able to do something like this:

```
if let _ = error {
    customCell.FaviconView.image = nil
    return
}
```

Otherwise, you'd have to figure out how to set the image to `nil` yourself. But that basic approach should do the trick.

**Update:** After some further discussion and looking at the source, it appears that the issue is with the `scrapeFavicon` method since it gets kicked off once for every reload of the cell and the previous job is never cancelled. Because of this, a cell can have multiple jobs running to get the favicon and the data loaded into the cell when the jobs complete would be completely random.

Comment: Why is it have to do with the error ? why not setting the image to nil at the awakeFromNib method ?

Comment: @Warhost Based on the available code, that seemed to be the possible point of failure. I guess the other thing to test is whether if you get beyond the error, if the `imageURL` always results in a valid `NSURL` instance (not `nil`)? And if not, what does the `af_setImage` method do if the URL is `nil`?

Comment: @OhadM I tried `self.FaviconView.image = nil` in the custom cell's awakeFromNib method. Didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @Fahim What also confuses me, upon inputting a new entry to the table, it randomly gets assigned one of the last few favicons.

Comment: @Warhost At this point, rather than hazarding guesses, if you can share the project with me, I'd be happy to take a look and see what is going on. If you are unable to do that, then I'm afraid I have no idea what might be going on.

Comment: @Fahim Very kind of you, check your mail.

Comment: @Warhost Got the invite. Give me a few minutes to do some checking and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139026/discussion-between-warhost-and-fahim).